# How to display in Kendo ui Grid Column a list of object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid

**VIEW:**

```
      @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ProductListViewModel>()
        .Name("ProductList")
        .Columns(columns => 
                            {columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
                            columns.Bound(p => p.Price);
                            ...})
        .Sortable()
        ...
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => Read.Action("GetProducts","Products").Data("additionalDataGrid"))
```

And in the ProductListViewModel is a list of MyListViewModel member, how to display it in the grid in more columns?

Comment: You can make a new model and then merge these two models in one and the bind the grid with new model